# set javascript variable using php echo doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

how can I pass `session['user_id']` to `javascript`?
I tried  `var user_id = "<?php echo session['user_id']; ?>";` within the body but it doesn't receive from php.

```
<?php session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    //user logged in = true;
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
?>

<body>logged in content</body>
//I put my js here


<?php 
}else{
    header('Location: fblogin.php');
    //echo "not logged in";
}
?>
```

Comment: did you put a script tag? If you output html directly, put the var stmt inside a script tag

Comment: And put that script tag either in the `<head>` section or the `<body>` section of the HTML page.

Comment: Your JS session var would look something like `var variable_name = "<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>";` which is was I use. Yours looks similar, so something else in your code is breaking it. So far, the first comment makes sense without seeing actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I use, with jQuery, (in a two part test). *Yet as stated in a comment*, make sure your JS is wrapped in `<script>...</script>` if you haven't already done so.

**Part 1** (set session names from form input)

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$_SESSION['myusername'] = $_POST['myusername'];
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $_POST['mypassword'];

echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo "<br>";

echo $_SESSION['mypassword'];

} // isset submit

ob_end_flush();
?>

<form action="" method="post">
Username: 
<input type="text" name="myusername">
<br>
Password: 
<input type="text" name="mypassword">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br><br>
<a href="sessions_test.php">check session name</a>
```

**Part 2** (view session names, if set) (`sessions_test.php`) which will indeed show the session name when viewing HTML source.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset( $_SESSION['myusername']) && isset( $_SESSION['mypassword']) ){

$myusername = $_SESSION['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_SESSION['mypassword'];

echo $myusername;
echo "<br>";
echo $mypassword;
}
?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
var player = "<?php echo $_SESSION['myusername']; ?>";

// alert (player);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add like this in your js:

```
<script>
  var user_id="<?php echo $user_id; ?>";
 </script>
```